# Defining Generic Methods

Tags: c#, generics

All, I have a method that is currently used to invoke DLLs of return type `bool`, this works great. This method is

```
public static bool InvokeDLL(string strDllName, string strNameSpace, 
                             string strClassName, string strMethodName, 
                             ref object[] parameters, 
                             ref string strInformation, 
                             bool bWarnings = false)
{
    try
    {
        // Check if user has access to requested .dll.
        if (!File.Exists(Path.GetFullPath(strDllName)))
        {
            strInformation = String.Format("Cannot locate file '{0}'!",
                                           Path.GetFullPath(strDllName));
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Execute the method from the requested .dll using reflection.
            Assembly DLL = Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.GetFullPath(strDllName));
            Type classType = DLL.GetType(String.Format("{0}.{1}", 
                                         strNameSpace, strClassName));
            if (classType != null)
            {
                object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
                MethodInfo methodInfo = classType.GetMethod(strMethodName);
                if (methodInfo != null)
                {
                    object result = null;
                    result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, new object[] { parameters });
                    return Convert.ToBoolean(result);
                }
            }

            // Invocation failed fatally.
            strInformation = String.Format("Could not invoke the requested DLL '{0}'! " + 
                                           "Please insure that you have specified the namespace, class name " +
                                           "method and respective parameters correctly!",
                                           Path.GetFullPath(strDllName));
            return false;

        }
    }
    catch (Exception eX)
    {
        strInformation = String.Format("DLL Error: {0}!", eX.Message);
        if (bWarnings)
            Utils.ErrMsg(eX.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to extend this method so that I can retrieve return values from a DLL of *any type*. I planned to do this using generics but immediately have gone into territory unknown to me. How do I return T when it is unknown at compile time, I have looked at reflection but I am unsure how it would be used in this case. Take the first check in the above code

```
public static T InvokeDLL<T>(string strDllName, string strNameSpace, 
                             string strClassName, string strMethodName, 
                             ref object[] parameters, ref string strInformation, 
                             bool bWarnings = false)
{
    try
    {
        // Check if user has access to requested .dll.
        if (!File.Exists(Path.GetFullPath(strDllName)))
        {
            strInformation = String.Format("Cannot locate file '{0}'!",
                                           Path.GetFullPath(strDllName));
            return "WHAT/HOW??";
        ...
```

How can I achieve what I want, or shall I just overload the method?

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: In your second block of code, that looks like an error condition. Wouldn't it be more appropriate to `throw new ArgumentException()`? As for the other returns, do what Heinzi suggests.

Comment: +1 I am not sure in this case. Sometimes it is clearer to define the cause of the error yourself as the Exception.Message can sometimes be cryptic for the user. However, having said that I am not sure this is one of those cases. Thanks for your time...

Comment: I agree with Jesse - if you fail to even find or invoke the method, you should throw. The user should expect that a return implies success. The managed world uses exception to communicate failures like this. Not specialized returns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
return false;
```

by

```
return default(T);
```

and

```
return Convert.ToBoolean(result);
```

by

```
return (T)result;
```

Comment: That's great thanks. Do you know where I can find out what the default values of each type are - it does not seem to be on MSDN or in the Language guide?

Comment: @Killercam [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc(v=vs.100).aspx), reference types are always `null`.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth One more quick one. The default(Boolean) is false, but what if instead of return false; I wanted `return true;`?

Comment: @Killercam You cannot do that and use generics at the same time. If you need to return a boolean in response to the state of the method regardless of the generic type, use `out` parameters that are strongly-typed bool.

Comment: @Killercam: Then you have to make a special case for Boolean, e.g., `if (typeof(T) == typeof(bool)) return true;`.

Comment: @Heinzi But that won't satisfy `T` so it won't compile under the generic method.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: True, the return statement must be `return (T)(object)true;` in this case.

Comment: @Heinzi Yeah, that'll work, no idea why you'd want to do that though :-)

Answer (score 4):

When you've not got a real value from the DLL, you obviously have to create a value from somewhere. The only way that works for every possible type `T` is `return default(T)` which gives whatever the default value for that type is (i.e. `0` for `int`, `null` for any reference type).

If you place type constraints on the type parameter you can get more options, but at the expense of genericity.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
    public static InvokeDLLResult<T> InvokeDLL<T>(string strDllName, string strNameSpace,
                         string strClassName, string strMethodName,
                         ref object[] parameters,
                         ref string strInformation,
                         bool bWarnings = false)
    {
        try
        {
            // Check if user has access to requested .dll.
            if (!File.Exists(Path.GetFullPath(strDllName)))
            {
                strInformation = String.Format("Cannot locate file '{0}'!",
                                                         Path.GetFullPath(strDllName));
                return InvokeDLLResult<T>.Failure;
            }
            else
            {
                // Execute the method from the requested .dll using reflection.
                Assembly DLL = Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.GetFullPath(strDllName));
                Type classType = DLL.GetType(String.Format("{0}.{1}", strNameSpace, strClassName));
                if (classType != null)
                {
                    object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
                    MethodInfo methodInfo = classType.GetMethod(strMethodName);
                    if (methodInfo != null)
                    {
                        object result = null;
                        result = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, new object[] { parameters });
                        return new InvokeDLLResult<T>(true, (T) Convert.ChangeType(result, methodInfo.ReturnType));
                    }
                }

                // Invocation failed fatally.
                strInformation = String.Format("Could not invoke the requested DLL '{0}'! " +
                                                         "Please insure that you have specified the namespace, class name " +
                                                         "method and respective parameters correctly!",
                                                         Path.GetFullPath(strDllName));
                return InvokeDLLResult<T>.Failure;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception eX)
        {
            strInformation = String.Format("DLL Error: {0}!", eX.Message);
            if (bWarnings)
                Debug.WriteLine(eX.Message);
            return InvokeDLLResult<T>.Failure;
        }
    }

    public class InvokeDLLResult<T>
    {
        public InvokeDLLResult(bool success, T result)
        {
            Success = success;
            Result = result;
        }

        public bool Success { get; private set; }
        public T Result { get; private set; }

        public static InvokeDLLResult<T> Failure = new InvokeDLLResult<T>(false, default(T));
    }
```

Or, I would write a TryInvokeDLL method, using an out parameter to return the result.

Comment: +1, very elegant. I think you can skip the `Convert.ChangeType(result, methodInfo.ReturnType)`, though. Since `result` has been returned by the method referenced by `methodInfo`, it must already have a dynamic type of `methodInfo.ReturnType`. Oh, and I'd add `strInformation` to the return object: `ref` parameters are ugly. ;-)